# SparkStreaming tasks fails with NullPointerException

Tags: kafka-producer-api, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm running spark job with kafka-clients:2.2.1 and

spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.3

The job is running in the following mode:

```
val scc: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(spark, "180 seconds")
val kafkaSink: Broadcast[KafkaSink] = ...
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...)
stream //. do some logic
.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) => 
     p.foreach { row =>
     val rowJson = convertRowToJSON(row)
     kafkaSink.value.send(kafkaOptions.topic, rowJson) }
}
```

The job is running but for some mini-batches, there are failed tasks with following exceptions:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:1010)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:916)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:897)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:774)
at com.outbrain.recs.rtap.kafka.KafkaSink.send(KafkaSink.scala:42)
at
```

[image]
What could be the reason for those exceptions?